# I am trying to connect to an API using WebSocket but I got this Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, api, npm, websocket

[Installation of the api on gitHub](https://github.com/binary-com/deriv-api);

```java
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const DerivAPI = require("@deriv/deriv-api/dist/DerivAPI");

// app_id 1089 is for testing, create your own app_id and use it here.
// go to api.deriv.com to register your own app.
const connection = new WebSocket(
    "wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=1089"
);
const api = new DerivAPI({ connection });
const basic = api.basic;

basic.ping().then(console.log);
```

but I got ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: You're trying this from a CommonJS module on Node, right?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the `"ReferenceError require is not defined"` error, remove the type property if it's set to `module` in your `package.json` file and rename any files that have a .mjs extension to have a .js extension.

package.json

```
{
  // ️ this should be removed if you want to use `require`
  "type": "module",
  // ... ️ rest
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the ES6 module syntax with the `import` and `export` keywords.

If you want to use the import/export syntax to import and export modules, set the type property to `module` in your package.json file.

package.json

```
{
  // ️ add this
  "type": "module",
  // ... ️ rest
}
```

You would have to replace the require and module.exports syntax with the import and export keywords.

Comment: I don't have the type:module and when I add it and try to use import I get another error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside module ,anyway thank you

Comment: Where are you going to implement the code, in node.js backend or what?

Comment: I am just trying to render it in the browser,

Comment: actually all what i want to do is to connect to this API :https://github.com/binary-com/deriv-api
 I want to get any kind of data from there and render it 
I will have this like a task in the interview

Comment: How do you include the library files in your code? with `script` tag?

Comment: Do you use npm or yarn?

Comment: i am using npm.

Comment: Basically, the instructions on github can help with the connection adjustment, and this : https://api.deriv.com/api-explorer  api explorer can help with finding the right request

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-bardeen-407big?file=/index.js Please have a look at it.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/8L8Q5AC.png

Comment: That package on its npm page says that it runs in Node and mentions nothing about running in a browser. *edit* not true, sorry, for browser use it suggests importing the DerivAPIBasic.js file with a `<script>` tag.

Comment: What do you mean by running in a browser? Are you in a learning course?

Comment: What's what I have asked you already, `script` tag

Comment: https://github.com/binary-com/deriv-api#using-the-html-script-tag